# C++: Searching in Process Memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++

By already given specific process' handle, how can I move further to search for a specific keywords(bytes, ints(2 bytes), text(an array)) in its memory in code, using VC++ ?

Comment: Can you reframe the question? Keywords don't exist after the program has been compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you want to scan through another's process raw memory. By definition, processes are and should be isolated from one another and have totally independent address spaces (your address 0x06573AF8 contains something entirely different from the corresponsing address in another process' address space).

However, there are a number of ways around this: in Windows, the classic answer is to write a specific DLL which you then inject into the address space of the other process. Take a look at [CodeProject for some hands-on advice](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx), or slightly more generally, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to use ReadProcessMemory. Also consider using WinDbg - it already has exactly this functionality.